# Having generic belongsTo in grails domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship, grails-domain-class

I have three classes in my grails project. What is the proper grails domain definition

```
Class A {

 List<Resource> xResources
 List<Resource> yResources

 hasMany = [ xResources: Resource, yResources: Resource]
}

Class B {
  List<Resource> zResources
  hasMany = [ zResources: Resource]
}


Class Resource {

  String title
   .....
     ..

 belongsTo = [A, B]

}
```

The above definition fails because i have not mentioned the mappedBy in Class A. How that can be avoided. I want the Resource class to be generic.
I don't want to restrict the Resource class only to the two classes, but i should allow it extend it to other. I also need to get the source reference from a Resource object. What should be proper GORM definition for this scenario.?

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 major issues in your code:

1. The properties `xResources, yResources, zResources` is double defined. Just remove the duplicate `List<Resource> ...` definition.
2. `hasMany` and `belongsTo` should have a `static` key word before it.
3. I'm not sure `belongsTo` can point to more than one class. If not, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code

```
Class A {
static hasMany = [ xResources: Resource, yResources: Resource]
}

Class B {

static hasMany = [ zResources: Resource]
}


Class Resource {

  String title
   .....
     ..

 static belongsTo = [a:A, b:B]

}
```